# How to customize width and height of Floating Action Button material ui component in React. Also the button does not show the edit icon correctly

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to add a Floating Action Button (FAB) on my app. Where I want to adjust its width and height to reduce its size using css. Also the button does not show the edit icon inside the button as expected.

Below are the code that I tried,

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-aryabhata-lhxr9)

## index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import './profile/profile.css';
import ProfileInfo from './profile/profile';

ReactDOM.render(
    <ProfileInfo />, 
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

## profile.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './profile.css';
import Fab from '@material-ui/core/Fab';
import Icon from '@material-ui/core/Icon';


class ProfileInfo extends React.Component{   

    render(){
        return(
            <div className='prof-main-container'>
            <div className='prof-items-container'>
            <div className='prof-pic-container'><img src="https://ik.imagekit.io/upgrad1/upgradlogo.png" className="prof-pic" alt="profile pic" /></div>
            <div className='prof-info-data-container'>
                <div className='user-name'>User Name</div>
                <div className='posts-follows-container'>
                    {/* <span className='posts-follows-item-first'>Posts:6</span>
                    <span className='posts-follows-item'>Follows:4</span>
                    <span className='posts-follows-item'>Followed By:6</span> */}
                    <span>Posts:6</span>
                    <span className='posts-follows-item'>Follows:4</span>
                    <span>Followed By:6</span>
                </div>
                <div className='full-name-container'>
                    <div className='full-name'>UpGrad Education</div>
                    <div className='full-name-edit-btn'>
                    {/* <Button variant="fab" color="secondary" size='medium'>
                        Edit
                    </Button> */}
                    <Fab color="secondary" aria-label="Edit" className='edit-btn'>
                        <Icon>edit_icon</Icon>
                    </Fab>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        )
    }

}

export default ProfileInfo
```

## profile.css

```
.prof-main-container {
    display: flex; 
    background-color: #5995DA;  /* Blue */
    padding: 20px 0;   
}

.prof-items-container {
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    /* justify-content: space-around; */
    padding: 0% 20%;
    /* padding-left: 500px; */
}

.prof-info-data-container{
    display: flex;
    /* justify-content: space-between; */
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0px 40px;
}

.prof-pic-container{
    padding: 15px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.prof-pic{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

.posts-follows-item{
    margin: 0px 60px;
}

.posts-follows-container{
    font-size: 11px;
    margin: 2px 0px;
}

.full-name-container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.full-name{
    font-size: 12px; 
    margin: 10px 0px;   
}

.user-name{
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 5px 0px;
}

.full-name-edit-btn{
    margin: 5px 20px;    
}

.edit-btn{
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

The expected edit icon is as below.

[image]

But actually it is rendering as below. Note that, no edit icon is displaying inside the button as expected instead it is showing "EC" inside the button.Please ignore the background color here.

[image]

Also, I should be able to adjust the width and height of the below edit button to reduce its size.But I am not able to do it using css. I tried adding a class named "edit-btn" inside profile.css but it does not work.

[image]

Comment: Can you share your code in a `jsFiddle or code sandbox`?

Comment: edited my question sharing the code in code sandbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using `classes` prop instead of `className` on your `Fab element`.
According to the documentation you should use the former.

Refer this link for the same :
[Material UI FAB props](https://material-ui.com/api/fab/#css)

I have updated my answer. Your `.edit-btn` class will work fine if you give it more `specificity`. Refer my code sandbox for the same.
Regarding your `<Icon>` can you help me understand what is `edit_icon`?

[code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-cache-plxli)
Do give it a try and see if it works. Also please share what you have tried so far.Thanks!

Comment: No luck. I have edited my question sharing the code in codesandbox.

Comment: Edited my answer. You have to give more `specificity` to your `edit-btn` class.
Like below.
`.full-name-edit-btn .edit-btn {
  width: 60px;
  height: 20px;
}`

Comment: give more specificity? May I know what does this mean?

And regarding edit_icon. I just copied this from material-ui. I assume that it is some keyword to show the edit icon. But that does not work.

Comment: I think this article might help you. `https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/`. It's one of the key concepts in understanding css better.
In short, the more specific your `css classes` the higher preference it get over other styles.

Comment: Regarding your edit_icon just copy pasting won't help. It is clearly given in their documentation.

The Icon component will display an icon from any icon font that supports ligatures. As a prerequisite, you must include one, such as the Material icon font in your project, for instance, via Google Web Fonts:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />`

which I think you forgot to add in your `index.html`.